# Jenkins/Hudson not building

Tags: msbuild, build, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins build server, however the build just doesn't seem to be running any of the build tasks in the 'build' section.

I've been trying to use msbuild, and also a simple shell script, but every time I do a build it neither runs the steps or throws an exception.

Each output just looks like this:

```
Started by user anonymous
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Also the server log doesn't show anything suspicious.

I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this, or had any ideas of how to debug it?

Comment: Can you please post your configuration for a simple build (that runs shell script). Configuration will be in ${JENKINS_ROOT}/jobs/[job_name]/config.xml . If you are not sure what your JENKINS_ROOT is, goto (http://[jenkins_server]/configure), you are looking for 'Home directory', it's almost at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build may be a matrix build without axes. If it says 'Configuration Matrix' anywhere on the job configuration page - that's a matrix job. Create another job choosing 'Build a free-style software project' option.

Comment: That's done the trick, such a silly mistake to make! Many thanks